# Gradle .execute method showing error after gradle update

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

My project was running perfect with gradle plugin version `3.0.1` after updating to version `3.4.1` I am going through sync failure.

Previously I was using wrapper `4.10.1` which is now updated to `5.1.1`.

```
afterEvaluate(new Action<Project>() {

@Override
void execute(Project project) {
    tasks.getByName("assembleRelease").doLast {
        tasks.copyReleaseBuild.execute() //error is here
        tasks.copyReleaseBuildToXX.execute()
        tasks.copyReleaseBuildToXXXX.execute()
    }
}
```

`copyReleaseBuild` task is written something like below...

```
task copyReleaseBuild(type: Copy) {
    def releaseDir = getProjectProperty('releaseDir')
    if (releaseDir?.trim()) {
    //if release folder is provided
    def releaseAarFile =
            getProjectProperty('sourceCodeDir') + "/android-corekit/kit/build/outputs/aar/kit-release.aar"
    from releaseAarFile
    into releaseDir
    }

task copyReleaseBuildToXX(type: Copy) {
        from "./build/outputs/aar/kit-release.aar"
        into "../kitwrapper/libs"
    }

task copyReleaseBuildToXXXX(type: Copy) {
        from "./build/outputs/aar/kit-release.aar"
        into "../kitwrapperapp/libs"
    }
}
```

I have been trying to resolve from last two days but nothing is working as I lack knowledge of groovy.

Please check error log I am getting while building the project...
[image: error log]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because you are using an updated version of gradle (check the [migration to gradle v5](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html))

> The following properties and methods of TaskInternal have been removed — use task dependencies, task rules, reusable utility methods, or the Worker API in place of executing a task directly.
>
> - execute()
> - executer
> - getValidators()
> - addValidator()

Now you can't call the `execute` method directly, but you have to use the tasks dependencies to obtain the same result.

Just define in your `build.gradle`:

```
task copyReleaseBuild {
    dependsOn 'assembleRelease'
    //...
}
```

and remove this:

```
afterEvaluate(new Action<Project>() {

@Override
void execute(Project project) {
    tasks.getByName("assembleRelease").doLast {
        tasks.copyReleaseBuild.execute() //error is here
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case you have to modify all the methods with the same logic.

Answer (score 1):

[Upgrading your build from Gradle 4.x to 5.0](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html)

The following properties and methods of TaskInternal have been removed — use task dependencies, task rules, reusable utility methods, or the Worker API in place of executing a task directly.

- execute()
- executer
- getValidators()
- addValidator()

in your case seems you have dependency between tasks: `copyReleaseBuild` must run after `assembleRelease`

so, this simple `build.gradle` represents this dependency:

```
task copyReleaseBuild {
    dependsOn 'assembleRelease'
    doLast {
        println 'run copyReleaseBuild'
    }
}
task assembleRelease {
    doLast {
        println 'run assembleRelease'
    }
}
```

and the command `gradle copyReleaseBuild` 
runs both tasks:

```sh
# gradle copyReleaseBuild

> Task :assembleRelease
run assembleRelease

> Task :copyReleaseBuild
run copyReleaseBuild

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

Comment: Can you please share example with respect to my question as I had already read this document but nothing exactly solved my issue.

Comment: added a simple example